# selenium-webdriver: select not working in Firefox 47

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select an option in a select form on a website with Selenium.

It used to work fine, but after upgrading Selenium and Firefox and switching to the Marionette Webdriver to make the upgrade work, my code doesn't work anymore.

The desired form gets selected and the code doesn't raise an exception (which it does if I give a wrong option), but the option doesn't actually get selected.

my Python code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("casetype_345"))
select.select_by_visible_text("1")
```

the correspondending html code:

```
<select id="casetype_345" class="nat_casetypelist_casetype" name="casetype_345" style="float: left;">     
<option value="0" selected="">0</option>   
<option value="1">1</option>   
<option value="2">2</option>   
<option value="3">3</option>
```

I tried to select.select_by_value wich doesn't change anything and select.deselect_all() before selecting the option which raises an exception.

Comment: Faced similar issue with my tests only solution that worked for me downgrade to previous versions!!

Comment: Indeed, a downgrade fixed this. I scared away from downgrading as I am not very familiar with Linux / Ubuntu yet and I only found the way to do it with the tar before, but with synaptic it's been very easy.

Comment: PS: My working combination is selenium 2.53.5 and Firefox 41.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/CHANGES) on the repo, the new beta drivers seem to support Firefox version 4x. It might behoove of you to check which version you have.

Side note: I am running the latest version of selenium with Java, and I can confirm that anything above version 45 is not functional at time of this post.